# Trouble setting up Arquillian tests for Wildfly app with Picketlink

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, picketlink

I'm trying to write Arquillian tests for a web app to be deployed on Wildfly using Picketlink. My setup worked before I added Picketlink and it looks like I can package and deploy my application without any tests (it doesn't work which is why I want the tests so I can develop). Here's my deployment:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive deployment () {
  WebArchive w = ShrinkWrap.create (WebArchive.class, "test.war");
  w = w.addPackages (true, "us.levk.willow", "org.apache.deltaspike", "org.picketlink");
  w = w.addAsWebInfResource ("beans.xml", "beans.xml");
  w = w.addAsResource ("persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
  w = w.addAsWebInfResource ("jboss-web.xml", "jboss-web.xml");
  w = w.setWebXML ("web.xml");
  return w;
}
```

Running a test results in deployment failure due to a lot of missing CDI dependencies; relevant log output here: https://pastebin.com/sTD1x1Ag

`beans.xml` adds `org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityInterceptor`, `jboss-web.xml` binds my app to context root, `web.xml` adds resteasy and this is `arquillian.xml`:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <!-- Sets the protocol which is how Arquillian talks and executes the tests inside the container -->
  <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <!-- Configuration to be used when the WildFly managed profile is active -->
  <container qualifier="widlfly-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
      <property name="jbossHome">${jbossHome:target/wildfly-10.1.0.Final}</property>
    </configuration>
  </container>

</arquillian>
```